# how to set a text over an imageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I am placing an application bar on the top of the screen and it looks as the following figure:

[image]

Now i want to set a text over the image, so that the image looks as follows:

[image]

How to set a text over an image? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please try the below Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your background image">


            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" 
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:singleLine="true" 
                    android:text="Subject"/>

            </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This should really be a TextView with the drawable set as a background

Answer (score 31):

If you simply want text centered over an image, all you need is a TextView, no image view.  Set `android:background="@drawable/yourImage"` on the TextView.

Comment: But this only works for static images.What if for example, a news app wants to set the headline across the image? The images and change for every news

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu `textView.setBackgroundDrawable()` and `textView.setText()`

Answer (score 22):

That's how I did it and it worked exactly as you asked for:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Use Relative layout for this

Comment: As I have found often, many of these no longer work.  In this case I had to change the "android:gravity" to `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Answer (score 8):

1. Use `FrameLayout` [(Tutorial)](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/)

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/lake"
        android:scaleType="matrix"></ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="@string/top_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bottom_text"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="50dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Or

2.Use an image as a background: `android:background="@drawable/yourImage"`

Answer (score 2):

there many way to display text over an image

1) u can make this image with text..
2) u can set background(this image) for textview.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put any view on to of any other view on a Relative layout you need to define the top level view below the low level view... for example

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If i guessed correctly you are trying to use Header for you sample..

Set Background as that image and Add text view to that like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="55px"
    android:background="@drawable/testheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">           
        <TextView android:id="@+id/quaddeal_header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
            android:text="Campus"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or else You have to merge the Layouts by using Framelayout.

Check this [Sample for Frame Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout to achieve text over Image as below:-

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtnUploadPendingPods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/com" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="hii"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</FrameLayout>
```