# Android - Display text over specific position of image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

In my Android app I have an ImageView which displays an image from assets. What I need to do is to display a text almost centered in the image (what I mean by almost centered is aligned to a rectangle which is near from the center of the image).
I know the (x, y) coordinates of this point (in pixels), but when I switch from device to device, of course, this pixels vary.
I have tried using dp, with no luck.

So, what I want to do is to display text inside this rectangle. I have the (x, y) coordinates of each point of the rectangle (in pixels relative to the emulator).

How can I do to make that design responsive?

Thank you

Comment: Please look at the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777749/how-to-set-text-over-an-imageview and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the image in a relativelayout... And add the textView(with centerInParent) to the relative layout...

Comment: Yes, but I still have a problem: which font size should I use so it's the maximum value so that Text fits into the area?

Comment: You can't know.. so you have to search for a library called AutoFit textview.. you will give height for your text view.. and the autofit textview will handle all the cases.. this subject is not simple as is seems

Answer (score 0):

Try making the position relative to the Image not the Emulator.

So when you go across different devices you can multiply both values by the same scale factor.