# Textview and edit text loses contents from Listview and recyclerview

Tags: android

First I used custom Listview, when i set some content on edit text and select value from dropdown list and after scrolling listview I lost my text view and edit text contents.

Then I use Recyclerview. but same happens with recyclerview too. I again lost contents from textview and edittext.

Comment: Of course there won't be any attribute as floating action button extends ImageButton which again extends ImageView!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html), I guess?

It subclasses from [`ImageButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html), so was not likely designed with text in mind, but rather, an image. An `ImageButton` in turn is also an `ImageView`.

### Other Peoples' Solutions

So, you could look up how people have gone about adding text on top of those more common elements. Here are just a few topics on this very site, that came up quickly:

- [Adding text to ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404582/adding-text-to-imageview-in-android)
- [how to set a text over an imageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777749/how-to-set-a-text-over-an-imageview)
- [How to show the text on a ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457030/how-to-show-the-text-on-a-imagebutton)

### My Ideas

One of several approaches that come to mind would be to implement the `FloatingActionButton`'s `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method, and then call [`drawText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) on the Canvas object it receives.

Another idea is to arrange to have a `TextView` shown on top of the `FloatingActionButton`.

Or, alternately, don't use `FloatingActionButton`, but something that more readily accepts text.

Comment: Just a suggestion to add to your list of solutions/ideas: a `TextDrawable`. There are several implementations readily floating around. The [simplest one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/master/src/com/android/camera/drawable/TextDrawable.java) comes straight from Google. [These](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/amulyakhare/textdrawable/TextDrawable.java) [two](https://github.com/devunwired/textdrawable/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/example/textdrawable/drawable/TextDrawable.java) offer some more features.